# CPU to GPU memory transfer - cudaMemcpy() vs Direct3D dynamic resource with Map()

Tags: cuda, nvidia, direct3d11

I have a live video streaming pipeline that performs RGB32 frame encoding to H.264. I am targeting NVIDIA hardware so I was planning to use CUDA to perform the color space conversion from RGB32 to NV12. I looked up examples with kernels that perform similar tasks and everything seems fine. However since a lot of people mention that the data transfer speed is the most critical point of CPU-to-GPU communication I was wondering does anyone have experience of which is a better way to feed the RGB32 data to the CUDA kernel:

- Using `cudaMemcpy()` (at least [this](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/592375-cudamemcpy--directx11/) topic states that `cudaMemcpy()` performs better than the OS graphics stack
- Using a dynamic Direct3D11 resource that is registered with cuda and updated from the user space code via `Map()`

If anyone has experience with this then I'd be glad to hear it, otherwise - benchmarking it is:)

Answer (score 6):

Since there was no activity I took the liberty of doing the benchmarking, I'll leave everything here so that anyone can use them or comment on improvements.

I compared the timings of 1000 iterations for:

- `Map`/`memcpy` to the mapped memory/`Unmap` on a dynamic Direct3D 11 texture in each iteration - **3ms per call**
- `Map`/`Unmap` on a dynamic Direct3D 11 texture in each iteration (to get a notion of the overhead of Map/Unmap) - **1.4ms per call**
- `UpdateSubresource` on a default Direct3D 11 texture in each iteration (from what I had read this should be slower than a dynamic surface if there are multiple updates per frame) - **2.13ms per call**
- `cudaMemcpy` from a casual pointer allocated with `new` to a `cudaMalloc` allocated device memory pointer in each iteration - **1.3ms per call**
- `cudaMemcpyAsync` from a casual pointer allocated with `new` to a `cudaMalloc` allocated device memory pointer in each iteration and `cudaDeviceSynchronize` after the last iteration - **1.25ms per call**
- `cudaMemcpyAsync` from a `cudaMalloc` allocated host memory pointer to a `cudaMalloc` allocated device memory pointer in each iteration and `cudaDeviceSynchronize` after the last iteration - **0.250ms per call**

Basically it seems that I should stick with Cuda since it is faster than using a Direct3D 11 surface for transferring data from the system memory to GPU memory.

Also seems that the `Map`/`Unmap` approch wins over the default surface and `UpdateSubresource` in scenarios with very frequent updates when `Map`/`Unmap` itself is called very rarely.

I'll post the benchmark code below (it is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/rubu/CudaVsD3D11MemcpyTest/tree/master)) - I'll be very happy for any feedback since there may be issues with the benchmark which could impact the results since I'm quite new to Direct3D 11 and Cuda.

```
// STL
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

// ATL
#include <atlbase.h>

// CUDA
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime_api.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "cudart.lib")

// DXGI
#include <dxgi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")

// D3D11
#include <d3d11.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string sDeviceName("GeForce GTX 750 Ti");
    std::wstring sDeviceNameWide(sDeviceName.begin(), sDeviceName.end());
    const size_t nWidth = 1920, nHeight = 1080, nIterations = 1000;
#pragma region Direct3D 11
    CComPtr<IDXGIFactory1> pDXGIFactory1;
    ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(CreateDXGIFactory1(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory1), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pDXGIFactory1)));
    ULONG nAdapterIndex = 0;
    CComPtr<IDXGIAdapter1> pDXGIAdapter1;
    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1 DXGIAdapterDescription1 = {};
    bool bD3D11AdapterFound = false;
    while (SUCCEEDED(pDXGIFactory1->EnumAdapters1(nAdapterIndex++, &pDXGIAdapter1)))
    {
        ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(pDXGIAdapter1->GetDesc1(&DXGIAdapterDescription1));
        std::wstring sDescription(DXGIAdapterDescription1.Description);
        if (sDescription.find(sDeviceNameWide) != std::string::npos)
        {
            bD3D11AdapterFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (bD3D11AdapterFound == false)
    {
        std::cout << "Direct3D 11 compatbile adapter named " << sDeviceName.c_str() << "was not found!" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    const D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL RequestedFeatureLevels = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL FeatureLevel;
    UINT nFlags = 0;
#ifdef _DEBUG
    nFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif
    CComPtr<ID3D11Device> pDevice;
    CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> pDeviceContext;
    ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(D3D11CreateDevice(pDXGIAdapter1, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN, NULL, nFlags, &RequestedFeatureLevels, 1, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &pDevice, &FeatureLevel, &pDeviceContext));
    std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> pFrame(new unsigned char[nWidth * nHeight * 3 / 2]);
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC TextureDescription = {};
    TextureDescription.Width = nWidth;
    TextureDescription.Height = nHeight;
    TextureDescription.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_NV12;
    TextureDescription.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    TextureDescription.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    TextureDescription.MipLevels = 1;
    TextureDescription.ArraySize = 1;
    TextureDescription.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    TextureDescription.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DECODER;
    CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> pTexture;
    ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&TextureDescription, NULL, &pTexture));
    CComQIPtr<ID3D11Resource> pResource(pTexture);
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE MappedSubresource = {};
    {
        FILETIME StartFileTime = {};
        ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&StartFileTime);
        for (size_t nIteration = 0; nIteration < nIterations; ++nIteration)
        {
            ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(pDeviceContext->Map(pResource, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &MappedSubresource));
            _ASSERT(nWidth == MappedSubresource.RowPitch);
            {
                memcpy(MappedSubresource.pData, pFrame.get(), nWidth * nHeight * 3 / 2);
            }
            pDeviceContext->Unmap(pResource, 0);
        }
        FILETIME EndFileTime = {};
        ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&EndFileTime);
        ULARGE_INTEGER StartTime = { StartFileTime.dwLowDateTime, StartFileTime.dwHighDateTime }, EndTime = { EndFileTime.dwLowDateTime, EndFileTime.dwHighDateTime };
        double fElapsedMiliseconds = static_cast<double>((EndTime.QuadPart - StartTime.QuadPart) / 10000.0f);
        std::cout << "Map/memcpy/Unmap total time: " << fElapsedMiliseconds << " ms, " << fElapsedMiliseconds / nIterations << " per call" << std::endl;
    }
    {
        FILETIME StartFileTime = {};
        ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&StartFileTime);
        for (size_t nIteration = 0; nIteration < nIterations; ++nIteration)
        {
            ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(pDeviceContext->Map(pResource, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &MappedSubresource));
            pDeviceContext->Unmap(pResource, 0);
        }
        FILETIME EndFileTime = {};
        ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&EndFileTime);
        ULARGE_INTEGER StartTime = { StartFileTime.dwLowDateTime, StartFileTime.dwHighDateTime }, EndTime = { EndFileTime.dwLowDateTime, EndFileTime.dwHighDateTime };
        double fElapsedMiliseconds = static_cast<double>((EndTime.QuadPart - StartTime.QuadPart) / 10000.0f);
        std::cout << "Map/Unmap total time: " << fElapsedMiliseconds << " ms, " << fElapsedMiliseconds / nIterations << " per call" << std::endl;
    }
    TextureDescription.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    TextureDescription.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    pTexture.Release();
    ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&TextureDescription, NULL, &pTexture));
    pResource = pTexture;
    {
        FILETIME StartFileTime = {};
        ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&StartFileTime);
        for (size_t nIteration = 0; nIteration < nIterations; ++nIteration)
        {
            pDeviceContext->UpdateSubresource(pResource, 0, NULL, pFrame.get(), 1920, 0);
        }
        FILETIME EndFileTime = {};
        ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&EndFileTime);
        ULARGE_INTEGER StartTime = { StartFileTime.dwLowDateTime, StartFileTime.dwHighDateTime }, EndTime = { EndFileTime.dwLowDateTime, EndFileTime.dwHighDateTime };
        double fElapsedMiliseconds = static_cast<double>((EndTime.QuadPart - StartTime.QuadPart) / 10000.0f);
        std::cout << "UpdateSubresource total time: " << fElapsedMiliseconds << " ms, " << fElapsedMiliseconds / nIterations << " per call" << std::endl;
    }
#pragma endregion
#pragma region Cuda
    int nCudaDeviceCount = 0;
    auto nCudaError = cudaGetDeviceCount(&nCudaDeviceCount);
    _ASSERT(nCudaError == CUDA_SUCCESS);
    std::vector<cudaDeviceProp> Devices;
    Devices.resize(nCudaDeviceCount);
    bool bCudaDeviceFound = false;
    int nCudaDevice = 0;
    for (; nCudaDevice < nCudaDeviceCount; ++nCudaDevice)
    {
        nCudaError = cudaGetDeviceProperties(&Devices[nCudaDevice], nCudaDevice);
        _ASSERT(nCudaError == CUDA_SUCCESS);
        if (Devices[nCudaDevice].name == sDeviceName)
        {
            bCudaDeviceFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (bCudaDeviceFound == false)
    {
        std::cout << "Cuda compatbile adapter named " << sDeviceName.c_str() << "was not found!" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    nCudaError = cudaSetDevice(nCudaDevice);
    _ASSERT(nCudaError == CUDA_SUCCESS);
    void *pHostMemory = NULL, *pDeviceMemory = NULL;
    nCudaError = cudaMalloc(&pDeviceMemory, nWidth * nHeight * 3 / 2);
    _ASSERT(nCudaError == CUDA_SUCCESS);
    nCudaError = cudaMallocHost(&pHostMemory, nWidth * nHeight * 3 / 2);
    _ASSERT(nCudaError == CUDA_SUCCESS);
    {
        FILETIME StartFileTime = {};
        ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&StartFileTime);
        for (size_t nIteration = 0; nIteration < nIterations; ++nIteration)
        {
            nCudaError = cudaMemcpy(pDeviceMemory, pFrame.get(), nWidth * nHeight * 3 / 2, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            _ASSERT(nCudaError == CUDA_SUCCESS);
        }
        FILETIME EndFileTime = {};
        ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&EndFileTime);
        ULARGE_INTEGER StartTime = { StartFileTime.dwLowDateTime, StartFileTime.dwHighDateTime }, EndTime = { EndFileTime.dwLowDateTime, EndFileTime.dwHighDateTime };
        double fElapsedMiliseconds = static_cast<double>((EndTime.QuadPart - StartTime.QuadPart) / 10000.0f);
        std::cout << "cudaMemcpy total time: " << fElapsedMiliseconds << " ms, " << fElapsedMiliseconds / nIterations << " per call" << std::endl;

    }
    {
        FILETIME StartFileTime = {};
        ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&StartFileTime);
        for (size_t nIteration = 0; nIteration < nIterations; ++nIteration)
        {
            nCudaError = cudaMemcpyAsync(pDeviceMemory, pFrame.get(), nWidth * nHeight * 3 / 2, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            _ASSERT(nCudaError == CUDA_SUCCESS);
        }
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        FILETIME EndFileTime = {};
        ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&EndFileTime);
        ULARGE_INTEGER StartTime = { StartFileTime.dwLowDateTime, StartFileTime.dwHighDateTime }, EndTime = { EndFileTime.dwLowDateTime, EndFileTime.dwHighDateTime };
        double fElapsedMiliseconds = static_cast<double>((EndTime.QuadPart - StartTime.QuadPart) / 10000.0f);
        std::cout << "cudaMemcpyAsync total time: " << fElapsedMiliseconds << " ms, " << fElapsedMiliseconds / nIterations << " per call" << std::endl;
    }
    {
        FILETIME StartFileTime = {};
        ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&StartFileTime);
        for (size_t nIteration = 0; nIteration < nIterations; ++nIteration)
        {
            nCudaError = cudaMemcpyAsync(pDeviceMemory, pHostMemory, nWidth * nHeight * 3 / 2, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            _ASSERT(nCudaError == CUDA_SUCCESS);
        }
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        FILETIME EndFileTime = {};
        ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&EndFileTime);
        ULARGE_INTEGER StartTime = { StartFileTime.dwLowDateTime, StartFileTime.dwHighDateTime }, EndTime = { EndFileTime.dwLowDateTime, EndFileTime.dwHighDateTime };
        double fElapsedMiliseconds = static_cast<double>((EndTime.QuadPart - StartTime.QuadPart) / 10000.0f);
        std::cout << "cudaMemcpyAsync with cudaMalloc'ed input memory total time: " << fElapsedMiliseconds << " ms, " << fElapsedMiliseconds / nIterations << " per call" << std::endl;
    }
    cudaFree(pDeviceMemory);
    cudaFree(pHostMemory);
#pragma endregion
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```